# SQL Ranking by blocks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Im sure the answer to this is going to end up being really obvious, but i just cant get this bit of sql to work.

I have a table that has 3 columns in:

```
User | Date         | AchievedTarget
----------------------------------------

1    |  2018-01-01  | 1

1    | 2018-02-01   | 0

1    | 2018-03-01   | 1

1    | 2018-04-01   | 1

1    | 2018-05-01   | 0
```

I want to add a ranking as follows based on the AchievedTarget column, is this possible with the data in the table above to create the ranking in the table below:

```
 User | Date         | AchievedTarget | Rank
----------------------------------------

1    |  2018-01-01  | 1               | 1

1    | 2018-02-01   | 0               | 1

1    | 2018-03-01   | 1               | 1

1    | 2018-04-01   | 1               | 2

1    | 2018-05-01   | 0               | 1
```

Comment: You want to generate rank based on what logic?

Comment: The rank column in the second table.

Comment: What second table?

Comment: Do you mean you literally want the first five rows to get the column values `1`, `1`, `1`, `2`, `1`? Because that's easy enough to do, but that seems quite arbitrary. Or do you mean you have two tables, and want the first one to look just like the second one? Or something else entirely? It feels like we're missing the "this table I have" you refer to, and we just have the desired end result.

Comment: As you notice, we are all out of clues as to what makes you decide for those ranks. What makes you give rank 1 to date 2018-01-01? What makes you give rank 1 to date 2018-02-01? Etc. There must be some rule you are applying. What is this rule?

Comment: I ***think*** this is a gaps and islands question.

Comment: Sorry i have edited the question, i rank to rank using the achieved tragets column so that the 2 Consecutive 1s end up being ranked as 1,2 and show as a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, based on that this is actually a gaps and island question. if so, this *does* result in the second dataset the OP has provided:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable ([User] tinyint, --Avoid using keywords for column names
                            [date] date, --Avoid using datatypes for column names
                            AchievedTarget bit);

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable ([User],[date],AchievedTarget)
VALUES (1,'20180101',1),
       (1,'20180201',0),
       (1,'20180301',1),
       (1,'20180401',1),
       (1,'20180501',0);
GO
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT [User],[date],AchievedTarget,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AchievedTarget ORDER BY [date]) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.TestTable)
SELECT [User],[date],AchievedTarget,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AchievedTarget, Grp ORDER BY [date]) AS [Rank] --Avoid using keywords for column names
FROM Grps
ORDER BY [date]
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
```

Comment: Yes this looks to do what i needed, also the column names arent real they are just used as an example that i can apply to the data i need.

Answer (score 0):

Other method:

```
with tmp as (
select row_number() over(order by date) ID, *
from  dbo.TestTable
)
select f1.*, NbBefore + 1
from tmp f1
outer apply
(
   select top 1 f2.ID IDLimit from tmp f2 where f2.ID<f1.ID and f2.AchievedTarget<>f1.AchievedTarget
   order by f2.ID desc
) f3
outer apply
(
   select count(*) NbBefore from tmp f4 where f4.ID<f1.ID and f4.ID> f3.IDLimit 
) f5
```